# Problema al remover listas dentro de listas

Tags: python, lista, funciones, python-3.7

este es el problema:

Tengo una lista llamada `a` la cual incluye las listas `lvl_1` `lvl_2` `lvl_3` y `lvl_4` luce de esta manera:

```
lvl_1 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
lvl_2 = [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
lvl_3 = [10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
lvl_4 = [15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
a = [[lvl_1], [lvl_2], [lvl_3], [lvl_4]]
```

Hasta ahí perfecto, ahora, yo tengo la siguiente función:

```
values = 0
deepness = 0

def show():
    global values, deepness
    a[deepness][values]
```

```
def go_down():
    global values, deepness
    values += 1
    if values > 4:
        values = 0
        deepness += 1
        show()
    else:
        show()
```

El código se ejecuta bien, el problema viene en el `if values > 5:` sucede que cuando indico que `deepness += 1` y pasa a la función `show()` cuando se ejecuta `a[deepness][values]` me indica que `deepness` se encuentra fuera del alcance de la lista `a`

¿Como tendría que hacer para que al ejecutarse `a[deepness][value]` me tome el valor de `deepness` y no a este mismo como elemento?

EJ: si `deepness = 2` y `values = 4` al ejecutarse `a[deepness][values]` elprograma lo lea de esta manera

Answer (score 0):

Tu problema es causado por que `a` contiene las cuatro listas definidas anteriormente contenidas en otra lista, esto implica otro indice. Al `a` estar formada por un solo elemento "padre" que contiene otro elementos, `a[0][1]` va terminar en error. Por otro lado, `a[0][0]` no, ya que accede al único elemento que hay. Te voy a hacer una demostración práctica:

Supongamos que tenemos tres listas (i,j y k), estas contiene los números de 1 al 10 que son divisible entre 2,3 y 5 (respectivamente). También existe a que almacena a estas tres últimas:

```
i = [2,4,6,8,10]
j = [3,6,9]
k = [5,10]

a = [i,j,k]
```

Este es una lista **bidimensional**, por lo tanto cuando se intente acceder al elemento más bajo (un número en este caso) se tendrán que usar **dos indices**:

```
print(a[0][0])

2
```

Si se usa como segundo indice el número 5 (un indice mayor al máximo posible), terminará en error:

```
  File "C:\Users\gabriel\Desktop\ejemplo.py", line 44, in <module>
    print(a[0][5])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

En esto se basa tu error, lo voy a explicar después. Ahora, veamos que pasa si contemos a cada lista en [] (otra lista) dentro de una lista:

```
i = [2,4,6,8,10]
j = [3,6,9]
k = [5,10]

b = [[i],[j],[k]]
print(b[0][1])
```

Salida:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\gabriel\Desktop\ejemplo.py", line 43, in <module>
    print(b[0][1])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

**Pero, por qué se da este error?**

Lo voy a explicar paso a paso:

> b[0] ==> [[2, 4, 6, 8, 10]]

Se accede al primer elemento de la lista, este es una lista con otra lista adentro

> b[0][1] ==> [[2, 4, 6, 8, 10],**X**]

Se intenta acceder al segundo elemento de esta lista. Notar que está lista que solo tiene una lista adentro, el elemento al que se intenta acceder se  representa con una **X**. Se está intentando a acceder a un elemento que no existe. Finalmente intentemos acceder con un tercer indice:

```
b[0][0][1]4
```

Resultado:

```
4
```

**La explicación de tu problema:**

Como dije anteriormente en el ejemplo 2, tu problema se causa a intentas acceder a un elemento que no existe. Realmente si existe, solo que está mal ubicado. La causa de esto está en como defines `a`:

```
lvl_1 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
lvl_2 = [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
lvl_3 = [10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
lvl_4 = [15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
a = [[lvl_1], [lvl_2], [lvl_3], [lvl_4]]
```

`lvl_1`, `lvl_2`, `lvl_3` y `lvl_4` ya son listas, en `a` las estás reconteniendo. Esto convierte a `a` en un array **tridimensional**, por lo tanto se tienen que acceder a los elementos con **tres indices**.

**Entonces, como lo soluciono?**

**La respuesta es que hay quitar los corchetes que encierran cada elemento de `a`**. Una definición de la lista sería esta:

```
lvl_1 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
lvl_2 = [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
lvl_3 = [10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
lvl_4 = [15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
a = [lvl_1, lvl_2, lvl_3, lvl_4]
```

Haciendo ese único cambio, el programa (funciones) debería de funcionar de manera correcta.

Espero que te haya servido, saludos!